# Downheap implementation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have the source code of `Downheap` in C language which will move down the elements without violating the heap properties (the value of each node is greater/lesser than or equal to the value of its parent, with the minimum/maximum-value element at the root.) at any nodes of the tree.

```
downheap(int k)
{
    int temp, i;
    temp = a[k];
    while(k <= N/2)
    {
        i = 2*k;
        if(i < N && a[i] < a[i+1]) i++;
        if(temp > a[i]) break;
        a[k] = a[i]; k = i;
    }
    a[k] = temp;
}
```

`N` is the total number of nodes of the array `a`. I questioned that whether this program can move down nodes from left to right to maintain the property of [complete binary tree](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html)? How to prove it because there is no property that the right node must be smaller/larger than the left one.

Comment: I think you got something mixed up there. A (complete) binary tree doesn't require any form of order. A tree is binary, if every node is connected to at most three edges (one for a parent node and two child-nodes) and that's it. You don't need to proof that the result is a binary search tree. You'll have a hard time proofing that anyways, simply because heaps don't have that property.

Answer (score 0):

```c
downheap(int k) // k is the index of the item in the heap 
{
  int temp, i;
  temp = a[k]; // Use temp to store the item
  while (k <= N / 2) // Make sure that we don't get outside of the heap boundaries
  {
    i = 2 * k; // Helper line to be used as an index for the children of the node
    if (i < N && a[i] < a[i + 1]) i++; // check which of the children is 
    // Bigger to exchange with the item
    if (temp > a[i]) break; // Item already in-place
    a[k] = a[i];
    k = i; // Exchange item with the children we found to be the biggest
  }
  a[k] = temp; // Put the item in its correct position
}
```

Hope the commendation is helpful